# In the UK, is there any (legal or similar) limit on bike+trailer length?

Tags: legal, trailer

With a couple of miles of quiet lanes, and around 10 miles of fairly straight bike path that takes me right to a river I'd like to go kayaking in.  I've got a trailer that my daughter is too tall for and which I could modify.  So I wondered about towing my kayak by bike.  The boat in question is already 2.3m long; when behind my hybrid it would mean a vehicle of over 4m.  This is only as long as a normal car. I have to admit, this is more for curiosity than something I'm likely to do, as there are awkward bits of bike path even for a normal-sized trailer

We've already discussed the practicality of towing boats behind bikes, this question is specifically about whether it's permissible (i.e. not forbidden either by law or by "...should..." clauses in the Highway Code).  I'm interested in the UK situation; answers for other jurisdictions won't get accepted but should get upvotes from me

Comment: Not an answer as I can't reference any legal text:
Bike trailers for kayaks exist and they to ship to the UK: https://carryfreedom.de/
In there FAQ they write that their trailers comply with European safety and transportation standards but also that you'll have to check the legal situation in your respective country ... and to apply common sense.

Comment: I've seen trailers that long on the path before, usually holding gardening supplies or harvest.

Comment: Another consideration is whether you can put the bike and trailer and yourself on+in the kayak, once you get to the water.  And still float.

Comment: @Criggie I'd lock the bike+trailer up, and either paddle back to them or lock the boat, run back, and pedal to fetch the boat.  I'd normally drive, and paddle back to the van at this spot.  It's a placid river we use for training, so ideal for seeing if I'm up to paddling again after my broken shoulder in summer

Comment: As far as I know there is no UK law as such, most likely as it's not the norm to tow using a bicycle, however there is regulations for Motorcycle which are different to car towing laws, the trailer must be no more than 1m wide and be clearly marked with unladen weight, when hitched it must be no longer than 2.5m from the rear axles. This applies to motorbikes 125cc or more. Not going as an answer as it's not for bicycles as such, just info

Comment: I never tried it, but have found out that someone I know tows a sea kayak, i.e. a much longer boat than mine,  behind his bike with no trouble (also in the UK)

Comment: What's the **width** for UK bike trailers? I was wanting just under 5ft so I take it not allowed??

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a legal requirement specific to bicycles anywhere.  There are width restrictions but not height or length restrictions for bicycles.

It would be "reasonable" to have a trailer no-longer than a trailer towed behind a motor vehicle so there's an existing precedent already set.

Basically length is governed by the corners you want to go around.  So a silly-long trailer combination becomes impractical on a bike path with chicanes or a small road.

Taking reasonable precautions with flags and additional lighting (even in daytime) will mitigate risk.

[image: From https://can.org.nz/node/12541]
From https://can.org.nz/node/12541

[image]
From https://www.cycletrailers.co.nz/

(I know the maker of these trailers personally but have no other connection)

Comment: There are a couple of spots where I'd have to get off and push through a chicane, but apart from that the path is really suitable.  It's an [ex railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_and_Bath_Railway_Path), so quite straight except for joining/leaving it and where the path crosses a heritage railway.

Comment: please would you link references to the bicycle width restrictions

Comment: @jhnc line 1 says "I can't find a legal requirement specific to bicycles anywhere"  however I'm making enquiries.  More-to-come.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the first sentence to be about trailers but the second to be about bicycles themselves. My bad.